# How can I assign AWS Cognito User Pools unauthenticated roles?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I keep reading Amazon documentation and popular tutorials / blog posts about AWS Cognito supporting unathenticated use. For example:

1. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html
2. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/browser-configuring.html#Using_Amazon_Cognito_to_Authenticate_Users
3. http://moonsault.co/2015/06/23/using-aws-lambda-app.html

And so on. However, the "unauthenticated use" checkbox is nowhere to be found when creating a new User Pool in the current (Sep 2016) User Pools UI: https://console.aws.amazon.com/cognito/

There's also no "Edit identity pool" button or dropdown anywhere. Below is a screen shot workflow demonstrating this.

So how do you setup a User Pool for unauthenticated use now?

1. If I try to create a new pool:
   [image: https://www.evernote.com/l/Ae_R0XW3zs5G45aWLDBTw4Oj8IbaPqj8LooB/image.png]
2. takes me here, no check box for unauthenticated use:
   [image]
3. If I choose defaults:
   [image]
4. Takes me here...no checkbox still:
   [image]
5. So I follow through and it shows me a success screen with no checkbox:
   [image]
6. So what if I try to use one of the identity pools I already have? I've read I should use an "edit identity pool" link, but I can't find that either.
   [image]
7. No drop downs or edit buttons in sight.
   [image]

Not sure what I'm missing here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unauthenticated roles is a concept for the identity pool in Cognito Federated Identities, what you're going through is Cognito User Pools. These are entirely different entities. You'll likely want to create an identity pool to get unauthenticated access configured, and set up your user pool as a provider if you would like.

The Cognito console's landing page has links to both.